# What is the best approach in java to call a C function running on another server?

Tags: java, c, rpc

What is the best approach in java to call a C function running on another server? My application written in Java and running on an application server on server 'A' and I need to call a C function running on another server 'B' that doesn't have java installed.

Should we build a web service on server B to accept requests from my Web application on server A? or just call it remotely using RPC? and what is the performance of both?

Comment: 0
down vote
These might help https://blog.jscrambler.com/rpc-style-vs-rest-web-apis/, What is the difference between remote procedure call and web service , Remote Procedure Call between Java and C

Comment: Thanks, GhostCat your kindness and for the quick explanation.

Comment: For REST services in C, see https://github.com/h2o/h2o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all:

> *Just* call it using RPC

There is no such thing as "just" when talking RPC. Unless you already have some CORBA or whatever solution in place, you will have to invest a serious amount of time to get this working.

Using a web service adds multiple layers of abstraction, which can affect latency. But of course, that is the more flexible solution.

I think it is fair (in 2018) to state: a reasonable architecture would provide some sort of (restful) HTTPS service on B. You should only look into other options if there are hard pressing reasons.